# como logro conseguir sacar información de un vector solo por un atributo del objeto en x posición?

Tags: java, array, poo

En un vector tengo diferentes libros, cada libro como atributos tiene su titulo, autor, stock. 
quisiera saber como identificar por alguno de sus atributos el libro en si

```
public void buscar (Libro biblioteca[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Escriba el nombre del libro a buscar: ");
        String busqueda = sc.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < biblioteca.length; i++) {
            if (biblioteca[i].equals(busqueda) { //aqui no tengo respuesta
                System.out.println("Libro disponible con stock de: "+ stock);                
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Libro no encontrado");
            }        

        }

    }
```

espero se entienda la idea general de mi duda. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que en la Clase Libro debes tener un **Método** que te devuelva el nombre del libro en String y también un método que te devuelva el stock en Int, supongamos que se llaman **getNombre** y **getStock**
entonces seria asi:

```
public void buscar (Libro biblioteca[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Escriba el nombre del libro a buscar: ");
    String busqueda = sc.next();
    boolean encontrado = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < biblioteca.length; i++) {
        //Usamos el equalsIgnoreCase para que compare mayusulas y minusculas por igual
        if (biblioteca[i].getNombre.equalsIgnoreCase(busqueda)) {
            System.out.println("Libro disponible con stock de: "+ biblioteca[i].getStock);
            encontrado = true;
            //Usamos break para salir del bucle si encontro la busqueda
            break;                
        }                    
    }
    if(!encontrado){
            System.out.println("Libro no encontrado");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//el encabezado del metodo lo tenes medio extraño, yo hubiera puesto

```
public void buscar (Libro[] biblioteca){
    boolean corte= false; 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Escriba el nombre del libro a buscar: ");
    String busqueda = sc.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < biblioteca.length&&!corte; i++) {
        if (biblioteca[i].getNombre().equals(busqueda) { 
   //en la clase libro tenes que tener el metodo getNombre();
          corte=true; //para que no siga buscando una vez encontrado.
            System.out.println("Libro disponible con stock de: "+ stock);                
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Libro no encontrado");
        }        

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la clase del libro debes incluir los Getters y los Setters, esto son métodos que te permiten acceder a los atributos de la clase libro, cada objeto creado de libro heredará esos métodos.
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp)

Su accedes a este enlace te hablarán mas detenidamente de los métodos de encapsulación, eso sí los atributos deben ser private para que se puedan acceder a ellos desde los Getters y los Setters, una vez echo esto, sin miedo se pueden acceder desde los Getters a los atributos del objeto libro que tengas en tu array de libros o en tu lista dinámica de libros y por tanto puedes hacer diferentes filtros para cada atributo.

```
public void buscar (Libro biblioteca[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Escriba el nombre del libro a buscar: ");
    String busqueda = sc.next();//Pedimos el nombre del libro
    for (int i = 0; i < biblioteca.length; i++) {
        //Usamos el equalsIgnoreCase para que compare mayusulas y minusculas por igual
        if (biblioteca[i].getNombre.equals(busqueda)) {//faltaba  un parentesis, el método para ver si dos cadenas son iguales es equals
            System.out.println("Libro disponible con stock de: "+ biblioteca[i].getStock);
   //Si tiene que mostrar mas datos es cuestión de mostrar mas atributos
    System.out.println("Libro del autor: "+ biblioteca[i].getAutor);
            System.out.println("Libro encontrado.";
            //Usamos break para salir del bucle si encontro la busqueda
            break;                
        }else{
            System.out.println("Libro no encontrado");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si quieres buscar por Stock tendrás que crear una variable int para el Scanner y buscar con un número, lo que implica no usar *equals* y usar el *==*

Comment: equals se usa para comparar cadenas de texto, en tu ejemplo está mal escrito puesto que debe quedar así: if (biblioteca[i].getNombre.equals(busqueda))

Comment: Por eso no obtenías respuesta en esa linea, faltaba un paréntesis después de búsqueda